# C# .NET application built in Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit doesn't run in Windows 7 32bit

Tags: c#, .net

I have built an application in Visual Studio 2012 Express, on C# .NET 4.5 on Windows Server 2008R2 64 bit. When I compiled, I made sure in build properties, platform target is set to x86.

When I copy the files from Release folder to my Windows 7 32, it crashes.

Here is error my system is throwing:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   fileupload.exe
Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   53b63c5a
Problem Signature 04:   FileUpload
Problem Signature 05:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06:   53b63c5a
Problem Signature 07:   c
Problem Signature 08:   6
Problem Signature 09:   System.IO.FileNotFoundException
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Comment: ..have you considered building it as Any CPU?

Comment: When you say it "crashes", what does the crash say? Are you sure you don't need any files outside the `Release` folder? Components installed in the GAC on the 2008 box? Does it work anywhere else? ... **What have you tried?**

Comment: @Simon Whitehead Do you mean Any CPU in Platform Target?

Comment: try to build it with x86 (32 bit) and check

Comment: "It crashes" isn't a particularly helpful description. Do you have .NET 4.5 installed on your Windows 7 box? Is there any error message when it crashes? Did you check the Windows event logs for information? There are a thousand things that could be wrong. Without more information from you, we'd just be guessing at the cause.

Comment: @jcl +1. Is there any code executed at all? Do you do logging at the entry point?

Comment: *System.IO.FileNotFoundException* Well there's your problem. Log your exceptions somewhere and inspect what file is not found.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Where do I put that?

Comment: *Where do I put that* Somewhere. Where you log exceptions is your business (message box, text file, database, The Cloud). But [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24567409/242520) basically tells you what to do.

Comment: @Jcl It says "FileUpload has stopped working"

Comment: @ta.speot.is I understand that, but to put a logger in the code, I need to know where the problem is happening. When I run it in Windows Server Machine, where I built it, there is no error at all.

Comment: [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24567409/242520) would be a good place to start

Comment: Show us your `Main` or `Load` function. Looks like you're loading a file that you haven't deployed with your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a work around for this problem. Went into References in the Solution Explorer and for each of the items, I made sure I set "Copy Local" property to True. I ended up with a lot of DLL files in the Release folder, but it ran in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

It is a file-not-found exception, could be as simple as forgetting to copy a file or not specifying the full path name.

Don't guess at this, implement a handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event and log or display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString(). It tells you where your code bombed.